# How to convert this linq from query syntax to method syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I was able to get this to work like I wanted it to, but I prefer the method syntax to the query syntax.

How can this be written with method syntax?

```
var data = (from stat in this._applicationDbContext.Stats
            where stat.SupId == this.GetCurrentSupId() && stat.StatType == 1
            orderby stat.WeekEnding descending
            group stat by stat.WeekEnding into statGroup
            select new WeeklyStat
                       {
                           WeekEnding = statGroup.First().WeekEnding,
                           Amount = statGroup.Sum(a => a.StatValue)
                       }).Take(6);
```

This is the original SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (6)  
    SUM([stat_value]) AS lessons_graded,
    CONVERT(DATE, [weekend]) weekending 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Stats]
WHERE
    stat_type = 1 AND sup_id = 1113
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(DATE, [weekend])
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, [weekend]) DESC
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because writing equivalent code in a different syntax or language is not what SO is all about.  We'll help you fix broken code. But if you want code translation you'll have to try somewhere else.

Comment: @SamAxe: Would it be on-topic if OP specifically stated which part was unclear?

Comment: @Stefan: I would think not.  Explaining functioning code is not something SO is *supposed* to be about.  Apparently some disagree with that assessment.

Comment: It would be on-topic if OP would show some effort and tell where the shoe pinches. Also, tools like Linqpad or Resharper do this in a wink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exercise is very mechanical for queries that have no joins.

The basic rule is to extract `stat` variable from the `from stat` clause, and stick it into each separate clause, like this:

```
var data = this._applicationDbContext.Stats
    .Where(stat => stat.SupId == this.GetCurrentSupId() && stat.StatType == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(stat => stat.WeekEnding)
    .GroupBy(stat => stat.WeekEnding)
    .Select(statGroup => new WeeklyStat {
        WeekEnding = statGroup.First().WeekEnding,
        Amount = statGroup.Sum(a => a.StatValue)
    }).Take(6);
```

The same thing happens after `GroupBy` - now you start using `statGroup` for your lambda's parameter.

Note that this is only one possible naming scheme. Since parameter names in lambdas are local to the lambda, you can use different variable names inside `Where`, `OrderBy`, and `GroupBy`:

```
.Where(x => x.SupId == this.GetCurrentSupId() && x.StatType == 1)
.OrderByDescending(y => y.WeekEnding)
.GroupBy(z => z.WeekEnding)
```

Obviously, using a consistent naming scheme greatly improves readability.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I tried to do similar to the above, but I think I had it out of order.